# How can i instead of using the new use malloc translation

Tags: c++

I have this code in c++ creating a 2D ARRAY table.

```
struct person
{
int age;
char name[64];
}
person **p;
p = new person*[256];
```

How can I translate just the part

```
p = new person*[256];
```

to C code using MALLOC.

thx

Comment: Have you read the `malloc` documentation? Or searched up tutorials for C memory allocation?

Comment: If you haven't, here it is: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html

Comment: Im familiar with malloc but not for 2d arrays

Comment: translating between two languages is by far not a trivial task (even if it is between c and c++). You should first understand what the code does, then forget about the code, then implement the same in the other language. TL;DR: you should actually ask: "How do allocate an array in C", the fact that you have some c++ code to do the same is only of little relevance

Comment: This is a 1D array of 256 pointers to person objects, not a 2D array.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog what about `char s[5][8]`?

Comment: 1) A pointer is not an array and can never be. 2) using `malloc` does not magically turn your program into C. It's a different language. If you use a C++ compiler, it's C++ and you should use the cannonical tools of the language. Oh, and `p` is neither a 1D nor a 2D array.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: There are very well 2D arrays in both languages. An array of pointers can't be a 2D array at all.

Comment: ppfft good point, my brain on Monday afternoons...

Answer (score 3):

```
p = malloc(256*sizeof(*p));

for(size_t i=0; i< 256; i++)
{
       p[i] = malloc(sizeof(**p));
}
```

Do not forget to ad code which checka if mallocs did not fail.

Comment: There is a `sizeof` missing.

Comment: Yes. My mobile eat it

Comment: That's why it is so utterly important to always regularly feed your mobile ... ;)

Comment: It is hungry indeed. 2%

Comment: ate it - this predictive text is killing me

Comment: @P__J__ eat it ;)